# Any way to track speed/efficiency of contact form submission?

Tags: wordpress, performance, blockchain, contact-form, contact-form-7

I'm looking for a way to measure the efficiency of a Wordpress contact form 7 submission. I'm working on a research project that involves making it so that anything entered by a user on a contact form is stored on blockchain instead of a mySQL database.

I'd like to test how the efficiency of submitting the form contents to blockchain and submitting them to a regular database compare. Is there any tool I can do this with?

P.S. Please don't waste your time saying the project "unnecessary" etc; I've heard that many times, and I know. This is merely a research project, I'm not actually trying to make this mainstream or something.

Comment: What do you mean by efficiency?

Comment: @RaghavSood I'm really not quite sure myself. Maybe something like how long it takes for the user-entered data to get processed and stored on a blockchain vs on a database? Or maybe something like how much more processing power it takes. I'd really like some sort of measurement that shows how storing entered data on blockchain is a bit less efficient than storing on a centralized database. Sorry if that was kind of vague, I don't have much experience with web development etc, this is my first venture

Comment: Neither of those would really make sense, since all of it depends heavily on which chain you are using, fee markets, how many other people are using the chain, and a number of other variables.

Comment: @RaghavSood I know. I'm just trying to prove that there isn't much of a difference in performance between a contact form operating with a centralized database and one linked with blockchain, that's all. I just wanted to know if there was a way to get any data to help me prove that.